# When does the soul enter the body at birth?

Tags: atma

I know this is kind of an atheistic and weird question. But people have asked me this in discussions and I was never able to answer it. And it seems a plausible argument against the theory that there is such a thing as soul.
I believe that there is a soul - jivatma - because I have experienced it.

But when does it enter at birth? 
Is it in the masculine part (semen) or in the feminine part (egg cell)?
Or is it in neither and enters exactly at the time of insemination?

Is this process described anywhere in our scriptures?